# How do I limit my autosuggest results to 5 results

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosuggest

I just want 5 results for my autosuggest box and dont know how I can do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated
heres my code:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="autosuggest" value="Type in a city or town" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" >
    <input type="submit" value="Search">

    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="result"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and heres my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
        var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
        $.post('php/search.php', { search_term: search_term }, function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
            $('.result li').click(function(){
                var result_value = $(this).text();
                $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
                $('.result').html('');
            });
        });
    });
});
function onBlur(el) { 
    if (el.value == '') { 
        el.value = el.defaultValue; 
    } 
} 
function onFocus(el) { 
    if (el.value == el.defaultValue) { 
        el.value = ''; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: As you are fetching data from the server using post , you can limit the data from the **search.php** also.

Comment: just add linit in your Sql query... problem solved

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to do it on the server. However, due to some reason, if it is not possible on the server, you can try following in JS. Here I'm expecting server is returning data in following format '<li>data</li>'.

```
$('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
    var search_term = $(this).attr('value');

    $.post('php/search.php', { search_term: search_term }, function(data) {
        //Edit Start
        var dataarr=data.split('<li>');
        var totalrow=(dataarr.length>5)?5:dataarrr.length;
        $('.result').html('');
        for(var i=1;i<=totalrow;i++){//neglectine first data as it will be blank
             $('.result').html( $('.result').html('')+'<li>'+dataarr[i]);
        }
        //Edit end

        $('.result li').click(function(){
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
            $('.result').html('');

        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit your search result in `search.php` file (php/search.php). You may do that like;

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5")
```